# Cronjob as user www-data - account is currently not available

Tags: permissions

If I run `su  www-data -c /usr/bin/php /ho....` I get

This account is currently not available. So I guess my cronjob will never work.

How can I get this working without breaking security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core of your issue is likely that "www-data" has a shell of /usr/sbin/nologin - and that is being executed as part of logging in prior to the command being passed to run.

Try something like the following to get that command working as root:

```
  su www-data -s /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/php /ho....
```

Of-course, crontab probably does not have this limit.  I did a quick test on my ubuntu 16.04 box with an equivalent user by simply adding the cron entry to /etc/crontab, and that worked without needing to invoke su or care about the shell.  The line might look like

```
 * * * * *   www-data  /usr/bin/php /ho....
```

Comment: Or just put it in `www-data`'s crontab.